# The C Programming Language K&R exercise 1- 9

Tags: c

I'm new on here and relatively new to programming logic in general. In an effort to develop my skill I've begun reading this fine piece of literature. I really feel that I am grasping the concepts well but this exercise seems to have caught me off guard. I can produce the program but some of the examples I've seen seem to introduce some concepts not yet covered by the book like the examples [here](http://users.powernet.co.uk/eton/kandr2/krx109.html). `inspace` seems to be serving a function that is more than just a variable created by the programmer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int inspace;

    inspace = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            if(inspace == 0)
            {
                inspace = 1;
                putchar(c);
            }
        }

        /* We haven't met 'else' yet, so we have to be a little clumsy */
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            inspace = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

In the next example, `pc` seems to be doing something in regards to counting spaces but I'm not sure what.

I managed to create a program that completes this task but it was using only the variable c that I created, thus I understand its purpose.

Comment: Please try to make the question very clear, rather than implying a question.

Comment: think of 'inspace' as a boolean (0 is false)

Comment: Aha, thanks alot for the fast help PW! Makes perfect sense :) neat

Comment: You run into weird code like that only because you are reading a dinosaur book on the topic of an obsolete version of C. There has been a boolean type present in the C language for 14 years. I would recommend to learn the C language from an updated source instead.

Comment: it seems as though this book is still considered a good tool for learning c language as well as programming logic. after getting through some more text I will probably just switch to a book on objective c. Besides, this book matches my retro glasses quite well.

Answer (score 2):

The objective of this code is copy text  and if there is more then one spaces `' '` consecutive print only one space.

Variable `inspace` is used to keep track of whether  last time printed char was scape or non-space.
if `inspace` is zero means a char was printed that was not space. and
if `inspace` is one means a last time space was printed.

So if `inspace` is zero  next time scape can be printed on reading a scape, and if `inspace` is one then next consecutive scape found so not to print space.

See `C` is current char read. (*read comments*)

```
  if(c == ' ')  // currently space read
    {
      if(inspace == 0) // last time non-space printed, So space can be print
      {
        inspace = 1;   // printing space so switch inspace 1
        putchar(c);   // print space
      }
    }
```

Next `if`

```
if(c != ' ') // A char not space read, its to to print unconditionally  
{
  inspace = 0;  // remember that non-scape print
  putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while but this is the answer I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, blank;
    blank = 0;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' '){
            if (blank == 0){
                printf("%c", c);
                blank = 1;
            }

        }
        if (c != ' '){
            if (blank == 1){
                blank = 0;
            }
            printf("%c", c);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inspace` is essentially a variable to indicate you are or are not in the "just seen a space" state. You enter this state after seeing a space, and you exit this state when you see a non-space. You print your input only if you're not in the `inspace` state, thus you do not print multiple adjacent spaces.

*I managed to create a program that completes this task but it was using only the variable c that I created, thus I understand its purpose.*
In your program, if the input is "hello       world", is that its exact output? The program you posted will output "hello world" (compressing the multiple spaces between the words down to one).

Comment: Yes it serves the same purpose...this is a cool way of doing it though now that i understand!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem but finally got a program that works.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

/* copy input to its output, replacing each
   string of one or more blanks by a single blank */

int main()
{
    int c, nspace=0;
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c==' ') ++nspace;
        else{
            if(nspace >= 1){
                printf(" ");
                putchar(c);
                nspace=0;
            }
            else
                putchar(c);
        }
    } 
            
}
```